# Is Russell's proof of addition with Peano's 5. Axiom valid?

Tags: peano-axioms

This is a follow up question to my previous question: [Why define addition with successor?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4795154/why-define-addition-with-successor)

In this one I'd like to ask about Russell's use of Peano's 5. Axiom to prove his definition of addition:

> Suppose we wish to define the sum of two numbers. Taking any number
> $m$, we define $m+0$ as $m$, and $m+(n+1)$  as the successor of $m+n$.
> **In virtue of (5) this gives a definition of the sum of $m$ and $n$,
> whatever number $n$ may be**.

I follow T. Tao's definition of the 5. Axiom as stated here: [Fifth Peano axiom — Properties of the natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4579259/fifth-peano-axiom-properties-of-the-natural-numbers?rq=1)

In Russell's case the property $P$ is the identity property of zero: $P(0) \equiv 0 + m = m$

Here Russell is not testing the relation P as true or false for zero but he defines the identity property of zero by using addition symbol "+".

But $P(n)$ and $P(n+1)$ are not true because neither $n$ nor $n+1$ has the identity property.

Since $P(n)$ and $P(n+1)$ are not true, the conditions for the 5. Axiom are not satisfied.

What's wrong?

Comment: This is just induction: let's use $S(n)$ rather than $n++$ to avoid too many $+$s when discussing addition.  For any $m \in \mathbb N$, $m+0=m$ so $m+n$ is defined for $n=0$, i.e. $P(0)$.  If $m+n$ is defined for $n=k$, i.e. $P(n)$, then consider $m+S(k) = S(m+k)$, which is defined, so $m+n$ is defined for $n=S(k)$, i.e. $P(S(n))$. Using the axiom, $m+n$ is therefore defined for all $m$ and $n \in \mathbb N$.

Comment: A good companion to Russell's book can be Friedrich Waismann, [Introduction to mathematical thinking: the formation of concepts in modern mathematics (1951)](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Introduction_to_Mathematical_Thinking/JWLDAgAAQBAJ)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Great book, very helpful, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :-)

Comment: @Henry What is the relation $P$ here? Looking at $P(0) = m+0$ I think $P$ refers to the identity property of zero.

Comment: @zeynel $P(0)$ is "$m+0$ is defined" here for any given $m$, which we know since "we define $m+0$ as $m$".  $P(n)$ is "$m+n$ is defined" for any given $m$, demonstrated using the axiom, i.e. induction over $n$.

Comment: @Henry Sorry, I still do not understand what $P$ is. What is the explicit definition of the property $P$ that we assume is true for zero, for $n$ and for $S(n)$? If $P$ is the identity property of zero as stated with $m+0=m$, then this property is not true for $n$ and for $S(n)$. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @zeynel $P(n)$ is saying that for a given natural number $m$ and any natural number $n$,  $m+n$ is a natural number. $P(0)$ is true because the definition of $+$ says that $m+0=m$ which is a natural number, while $P(n)$ is true using the induction in the axiom.  You can go further and show that $m+n$ changes when $n$ changes and that $0+n=n$.

Comment: @Henry Thanks. That was helpful. Do I understand correctly that $P(n)$ is a theorem that says $P(n) = m + n \in \mathbb{N}$ ? Can this be proved simply with the 2. Axiom: $P_2 = n+1 \in \mathbb{N}$ without using the 5. Axiom? Because, $(m+n) + 1 \in \mathbb{N}$ by $P_2$. Is this correct? Why do we have to use induction?

Comment: @zeynel You want to show addition $m+n$ makes sense with this definition.  Once you have done that, you can show it has other properties you want, such as $0+n=n$ and more generally $m+n=n+m$.

Comment: @Henry I guess by "this definition" you mean $m+0=m$ which you called "the definition of +". To me, $m+0=m$ cannot be a definition of "​+". A definition of "​+" should be something like: "​+ := {definition of the addition operator "​+​"} Russell is not defining addition, he is using addition to define the identity property of zero.

Comment: @Henry And I don't understand how one can show that $m+n$ makes sense. Russell proposes to define $m+n$ then he rewrites the same expression $m+n$ for the special case $n=0$ as $m+0=m$. He never defined "+" but he uses it in his definitions. He proposes to define "​+" but he uses "​+" in his definitions.

Comment: @Henry And his definitions are identities. I don't know what new information can be obtained from $m+n+1 = m+n+1$
.

Comment: @zeynel $m+0=m$ is part of the definition you quote for $+$, while $0+n=n$ is a theorem which can be proved.  Since $+$ is a binary operator, $m+n+1$ is not meaningful, at least until you have $m+(n+1)=(m+n)+1$ as an axiom or theorem

Comment: @Henry In your comment yesterday https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4803539/is-russells-proof-of-addition-with-peanos-5-axiom-valid?noredirect=1#comment10221082_4803539 did we define or prove addition? No. We proved what $P(n)$ states, namely, $m+n \in \mathbb{N}$. We assumed addition to prove that $m+n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4):

We have to start from the definition of *sum* in terms of $0$ and *sucecssor*:

> $m+0=m$

and:

> $m+s(n)=s(m+n)$,

and then we have to use induction to prove that the definition "works", i.e. "for every natural number $m$ there is natural number $n$ satisfying the definition and that this number is *unique*".

The relevant property $P(m)$ will be: $\forall y \exists z(m+y=z)$.

First step, to prove it for $0$, i.e. to prove that $\exists z(m+0=z)$. The result is immediate from the definition.

The next step, according to Russell's Axiom 5 (induction), will be: assume that the above holds for $m$ and prove that it holds also for $s(m)$.

See [Addition of natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3830023/addition-of-natural-numbers-in-edmund-landaus-foundation-of-analysis) for details. The same in **Ch.2.2 Addition** of Tao's Analysis I (page 24-on).

Comment: "$\exists z(m+0=z)$" Should this be written with $z$ not $m$: $\exists z(z+0=z)$ ?

Comment: @zeynel - no; for an $m$ whatever, we have to prove that there is a unique result of the *add* operation. This is by induction and the base step amounts to proving that the result of "add zero" exists, i.e. that "there is a $z$ such that $m+0=z$".

Comment: I understand that Russell uses Peano's 5. Axiom to prove that addition is valid for all numbers. Thanks for making this clear for me. But I don't see how this is a definition of addition. You write $m+0=m$ as the first part of the 5. Axiom. I read this as "the sum of $m$ and 0 is $m$." This means that Russell assumes addition. He uses addition to state the identity property of zero. Are you saying that $m+0=0$ is not an addition operation?

Comment: @zeynel - see Russell's quote above: "we define m+0 as m, and m+(n+1) as the successor of m+n." This is the standard def of sum: Induction is needed to prove that the def is good. Compare with "round square=(def) a square that is circular". It is a definition, but this does not mean that round squares exist.

Comment: I still don't get it. The definition is, $m+0=m$". If you write "...that "there is a  such that +0=" you are simply saying that $m=z$. What's the point?